# Android socket to trace location on google map

Tags: android, sockets

i am trying to make a server program for android phone which will receive location from a client program written in c. this client program is sitting on a beagle board and fetching its location from a gps device. Now my problem is i dont have any idea about android programming or java programming???. please help me out. need your guidance and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is really simple and easy to understand : you have to learn how to use Java and the Android SDK. Nothing more to say. You can start here : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html